# What is the derivative of the Jacobi_Amplitude_Function (u, m) where u and m are non-constant functions of the independent variable x?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

While the derivative of the Jacobi Amplitude Function has been discussed to detailed extent (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiAmplitude.html), this is only the case for situations wherein m is a constant. What is the derivative of the Jacobi Amplitude function in situations where u and m are both functions of x, rather than just m?

Side/Extra Note: What is the proof for the derivative and can the same methodology be applied to other Jacobi Elliptic functions like sn(u,m) , cn(u,m) , and dn(u,m)?